# Inactivity, disconnecting from the service - using GoogleApiClient in Service

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client, google-drive-android-api, appdata

I am creating a service to upload files to **Google Drive App Data Folder** using **Google Drive Android API**.

I initialized the `GoogleApiClient` in the `onCreate()` method of the service. Then, I have written the code to upload the file to Google Drive in the overridden `onConnected()` method of the `GoogleApiClient'.

The problem I am facing is that, when I start the `Service`, The `onCreate()` method gets called. In this method, the `GoogleApiClient` object is initialized and the `connect()` function is called. Afterwards, before  the `onConnect()` is called (when `GoogleApiClient` is connected successfully), the following message is shown in the log

**"Inactivity, disconnecting from the service"**

So, the `onConnect()` method is never called and my file upload code is never executed. Please find the code snippet below. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
public class GDriveFileUploadService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private static final String TAG = GDriveFileUploadService.class.getSimpleName();
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public GDriveFileUploadService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG,"Initializing GoogleApiClient..");
    this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(GDriveFileUploadService.this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .build();

    this.mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG,"GoogleApiClient connected in service");
    //Code to upload file to Google Drive
}

//Other functions..
```

}

Comment: You may want to check the documentation on [Authorizing Android Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) and see how to reconnect the GoogleApiClient.

Comment: Also check the [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) public methods like [reconnect()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#reconnect()), [connect ()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#connect()), [disconnect ()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#disconnect()) to help you manage resuming your connection GoogleApiClient.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I feel that the problem is not with the `GoogleApiClient`. The `Service` is not waiting until the `GoogleApiClient` gets connected and gets destroyed. So how can we make sure that the service stays alive until the `onConnected()` function is called?

Answer (score 0):

use this    `JobService`    and

First you need to create a boot Service that runs the main service

```
@TargetApi( Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP )
public class BootService extends JobService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        if ( PreferenceManager.getToken(BootService.this) != null && !PreferenceManager.isNeedProvideInfo(this)) {
            startService(new Intent(BootService.this, MainService.class));
        }
    }, 1000);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // service On start
    return START_STICKY;

  ...
 }

}
```

The main service should be this way

```
public class MainService extends JobIntentService {
```